# Wygwam fullscreen toolbar not showing up in Firefox

Tags: wygwam

Wygwam 3.1.1 and EE v2.6.1 - Build Date: 20130506

I noticed today that the in Firefox 23, after clicking on the "maximize" option in the toolbar, the entire tool set disappears when in full screen, compared to Chrome, where the toolbar is positioned at the top of the screen and visible even when scrolling.

Bug?

Comment: I’m not able to reproduce that with FF 23. Can you try clearing your browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

Gah.  A restart fixed it :-|  Thank you!